# Carousel control buttons only work on one page

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress, carousel, advanced-custom-fields

I'm working on a map that can display an information on click on each city.
The information contains images slider carousel (bootstrap 5).
The next/prev buttons only works on one city.
I'm not sure if I have to change my javascript or what is the root problem?
I attached the code that has details of 2 cities. (I have total of 31 cities)

I actually am working on WordPress, using ACF Nested Repeater.
My code for WordPress looks like as shown below.

Please give me any suggestion.
This a my first post here, hope to get some help around here.
Thanks in advance!

````
    <div class="col-12 col-md-4" id="lacartecommunes">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="653.656" height="932.182" viewBox="0 0 653.656 932.182">
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="clip-path">
      <path id="Tracé_1" data-name="Tracé 1" d="M653.656,0H0V932.182H653.656" transform="translate(0 0)" fill="none"></path>
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
  <pattern id="diagonalHatch" width="10" height="10" patternTransform="rotate(45 0 0)" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
  <line x1="0" y1="1" x2="2" y2="4" style="stroke:#B79A20; stroke-width:15"></line>
</pattern>
  <path id="poule" data-name="Tracé 175" ></path>
  <path id="claveisolles" data-name="Tracé 176"></path>
</svg>

    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-md-6" id="infoscommunes">
        <div class="row click_pour_info hide">
            <div class="col-8 col-md-8" id="text_click">
                <h2 data-uw-styling-context="true">Cliquez sur les communes pour en savoir en<strong data-uw-styling-context="true">COR</strong>e plus sur le territoire !</h2>
            </div>
        </div>              
        <div id="commune_info_claveisolles" class="row hide">
            <h3 class="col-12 col-md-12" style="text-align: left !important" data-uw-styling-context="true">Claveisolles</h3>
            <div class="col-12 col-md-6 photo_commune">
                <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
                    <div class="carousel-indicators">
                        <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="0" class="active" aria-current="true"></button>     
                        <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="1" class=""></button>       
                    </div>
                    <div class="carousel-inner map">        
                        <div class="carousel-item map active" style="background-image: url(https://rvcom211b-corouestrhodanien.pf7.wpserveur.net/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/Vue-ST-FORGEUX_2020-09-23_©COR-2-scaled.jpg)">              
                        </div>                          
                        <div class="carousel-item map" style="background-image: url(https://rvcom211b-corouestrhodanien.pf7.wpserveur.net/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/Vue-Tarare_2021-06-22_©COR-2-scaled.jpg)">             
                        </div>                                  
                    </div>  
                    <button class="carousel-control-prev map" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide="prev">
                        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                        <span class="visually-hidden" data-uw-styling-context="true">Précédent</span>
                    </button>
                    <button class="carousel-control-next map" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide="next">
                        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                        <span class="visually-hidden" data-uw-styling-context="true">Suivant</span>
                    </button>
                </div>                                      
            </div>
            <div class="col-12 col-md-6 descr_commune"> <p></p><p data-uw-styling-context="true"><strong data-uw-styling-context="true">Maire : </strong>Dominique Despras <strong data-uw-styling-context="true">Code Postal : </strong>69870<br>
<strong data-uw-styling-context="true">Superficie : </strong>2833 hectares <strong data-uw-styling-context="true">Altitude : </strong>394 mètres <strong data-uw-styling-context="true">Population : </strong>749 habitants<br>
<strong data-uw-styling-context="true">Horaires d’ouverture de la mairie : </strong><br>
mardi, jeudi, vendredi, samedi de 9h30 à 11h30<br>
mercredi de 17h à 19h</p>
<p data-uw-styling-context="true"><strong data-uw-styling-context="true">Tel. : </strong>04 74 02 06 54 <strong data-uw-styling-context="true">Fax : </strong>04 74 02 01 95<br>
<a href="http://www.ouestrhodanien.fr/#"><strong data-uw-styling-context="true">E-mail : </strong><span class="mel2" data-uw-styling-context="true">mairie@claveisolles.fr</span></a><br>
<a href="http://www.claveisolles.fr" target="_blank" rel="noopener" data-uw-styling-context="true"><strong data-uw-styling-context="true">Site internet : </strong>http://www.claveisolles.fr</a></p>
<p></p></div>   
        </div>
                
        <div id="commune_info_poule" class="row hide">
            <h3 class="col-12 col-md-12" style="text-align: left !important" data-uw-styling-context="true">Poule-les-Echarmeaux</h3>
            <div class="col-12 col-md-6 photo_commune">             
                <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
                    <div class="carousel-indicators">
                        <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="0" class="active" aria-current="true"></button>
                        <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="1" class=""></button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="carousel-inner map">        
                        <div class="carousel-item map active" style="background-image: url(https://rvcom211b-corouestrhodanien.pf7.wpserveur.net/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/IMG_0245-scaled.jpg)">              
                        </div>  
                        <div class="carousel-item map" style="background-image: url(https://rvcom211b-corouestrhodanien.pf7.wpserveur.net/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/Vue-Thizy-Les-Bourgs_2021-04-07_©COR-10-scaled.jpg)">              
                        </div>
                    </div>  
                    <button class="carousel-control-prev map" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide="prev">
                        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                        <span class="visually-hidden" data-uw-styling-context="true">Précédent</span>
                    </button>
                    <button class="carousel-control-next map" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide="next">
                        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                        <span class="visually-hidden" data-uw-styling-context="true">Suivant</span>
                    </button>
                </div>                                      
            </div>
            <div class="col-12 col-md-6 descr_commune"> <p></p><p data-uw-styling-context="true"><strong data-uw-styling-context="true">Maire : </strong>Aymeric Champale <strong data-uw-styling-context="true">Code Postal : </strong>69870<br>
<strong data-uw-styling-context="true">Superficie : </strong>3123 hectares <strong data-uw-styling-context="true">Altitude : </strong>450 mètres <strong data-uw-styling-context="true">Population : </strong>1123 habitants</p>
<p data-uw-styling-context="true"><strong data-uw-styling-context="true">Horaires d’ouverture de la mairie : </strong><br>
lundi et vendredi de 14h à 17h<br>
mardi, mercredi, jeudi et samedi de 9h à 12h</p>
<p data-uw-styling-context="true"><strong data-uw-styling-context="true">Tel. : </strong>04 74 03 64 48 <strong data-uw-styling-context="true">Fax : </strong>04 74 03 68 71<br>
<a href="http://www.ouestrhodanien.fr/#"><strong data-uw-styling-context="true">E-mail : </strong><span class="mel2" data-uw-styling-context="true">secretariat@poulelesecharmeaux.fr</span></a><br>
<a href="http://www.poulelesecharmeaux.fr" target="_blank" rel="noopener" data-uw-styling-context="true"><strong data-uw-styling-context="true">Site internet : </strong>http://www.poulelesecharmeaux.fr</a></p>
<p></p></div>           
        </div>            
    </div>
    
</section>

<script>
$("#lacartecommunes").click(function(ev){
        var target = $(ev.target);
        var targetId = target.attr('id');
        if(targetId == 'claveisolles') {
          $(".click_pour_info").removeClass("show").addClass('hide');
          $(".show").removeClass("show").addClass('hide'); 
          $("#commune_info_claveisolles").removeClass('hide').addClass("show");
        }
        });
$("#lacartecommunes").click(function(ev){
        var target = $(ev.target);
        var targetId = target.attr('id');
        if(targetId == 'poule') {
          $(".click_pour_info").removeClass("show").addClass('hide');
          $(".show").removeClass("show").addClass('hide'); 
          $("#commune_info_poule").removeClass('hide').addClass("show");
        }
        });
</script>

//code wordpress
<section id="carte_communes" class="row justify-content-md-center">
    <div class="col-12 col-md-4"  id="lacartecommunes">
    <?php get_template_part('carte_communes', 'index');?>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-md-6"  id="infoscommunes">
        <div class="row info_cor">
            <div class="col-12 col-md-6 logo_info_cor">
                <img src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/images/logo_cor_bloc.png" title="COR - Communauté de Communes Ouest Rhodanien" ></div>
            <div class="col-12 col-md-6 text_info_cor"><?php the_field('infos_cor', 'option'); ?></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row click_pour_info">
            <div class="col-8 col-md-8" id="text_click">
                <h2 >Cliquez sur les communes pour en savoir en<strong>COR</strong>e plus sur le territoire !</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
                <?php while( have_rows('les_communes_cor', 'option') ): the_row();
                // vars
                $photo = get_sub_field('photo_commune_cor', 'option');
                $nom_commune = get_sub_field('nom_commune_cor', 'option');
                $slug_commune = get_sub_field('identifiant_commune', 'option');
                $descript_commune = get_sub_field('descriptif_commune_cor', 'option');
                ?>
            
        <div id="commune_info_<?php echo $slug_commune; ?>" class="row " >
            <h3 class="col-12 col-md-12" style="text-align: left !important"><?php echo $nom_commune; ?></h3>
            <div class="col-12 col-md-6 photo_commune" >
                
                <?php if( have_rows('photo_commune_cor') ):
                        $i = 1; // Set the increment variable
                        $nombre = 0;
                        echo '<div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
                        <div class="carousel-indicators">
  ';
  
    // loop through the rows of data for the tab header
    while ( have_rows('photo_commune_cor') ) : the_row();
    ?>
    
    <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="<?php echo $nombre;?>" class="<?php if($nombre == 0) echo 'active';?>"></button>
            
    <?php   $nombre++; // Increment the increment variable  
    
    endwhile; //End the loop 
     wp_reset_postdata();  
        
    echo    '</div>
          <div class="carousel-inner map">';
  
        
                        // loop through the rows of data for the tab header
                        while ( have_rows('photo_commune_cor') ) : the_row();
            
                        $image = get_sub_field('photo_commune_slider');
            
                        ?>
        
                        <div class="carousel-item map <?php if($i == 1) echo 'active';?>" style="background-image: url(<?php echo $image['url']; ?>)">              
                        </div>
    
                                                    
                    <?php   $i++; // Increment the increment variable
                    endwhile; //End the loop 
                    wp_reset_postdata();
        
                    echo '
                    
                    </div>  
                    <button class="carousel-control-prev map" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators"  data-bs-slide="prev">
                        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                        <span class="visually-hidden">Précédent</span>
                    </button>
                    <button class="carousel-control-next map" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators"  data-bs-slide="next">
                        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                        <span class="visually-hidden">Suivant</span>
                    </button>
                    </div>';
    
                    else :
                    // no rows found
            
                    endif; ?>
                     <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
                    
            </div>
            <div class="col-12 col-md-6 descr_commune"> <p><?php echo $descript_commune; ?></p></div>
            
        </div>
    
             <?php endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
<?php  wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

    </div>
    
</section>```
````

Comment: It's really hard to diagnose this because it's a ton of code and nothing testable. I would suggest making a testable snippet (no php) - and it's easy. Just view-source on your actual page and copy the rendered HTML into a snippet here. Include any relevant script and any necessary external script tags. Use the snippet button in the toolbar to get started.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code on jsfiddle, Click [here](https://jsfiddle.net/webdevrvcom/jfm234p9/)!

Normally all the information are display:none;
But I can't make it work on jsfiddle.

```
    <div id="commune_info_poule" class="row hide">
  <h3 class="col-12 col-md-12" style="text-align: left !important" data-uw-styling-context="true">Poule-les-Echarmeaux</h3>
  <div class="col-12 col-md-6 photo_commune">

    <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
      <div class="carousel-indicators">

        <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="0" class=""></button>


        <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="1" class="active" aria-current="true"></button>

      </div>
      <div class="carousel-inner map ">
        <div class="carousel-item map" style="background-image: url(https://rvcom211b-corouestrhodanien.pf7.wpserveur.net/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/TiersLieu_2021-02-25_©COR-17-scaled.jpg)">
        </div>



        <div class="carousel-item map active" style="background-image: url(https://rvcom211b-corouestrhodanien.pf7.wpserveur.net/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/ECOMUSEE_vue-drone_2020-02-1-scaled.jpg)">
        </div>




      </div>
      <button class="carousel-control-prev map" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide="prev">
                    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <span class="visually-hidden" data-uw-styling-context="true">Précédent</span>
                </button>
      <button class="carousel-control-next map" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide="next">
                    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <span class="visually-hidden" data-uw-styling-context="true">Suivant</span>
                </button>
    </div>
  </div>
```

But you can see that I have 2 slides, carousel indicator only works on one of them.